# Convert swt.grapics.image to awt.image possible?

Tags: java, image, swt, awt

I am using `eclipse.swt.graphics.image` to render `pdf` files, but i want to draw them on a jLabel using `awt.image` like this `label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));`. Is it possible? then how?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  The 3rd Google link of [Convert swt.graphics.image to awt.image](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/ConvertbetweenSWTImageandAWTBufferedImage.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.DirectColorModel;
import java.awt.image.IndexColorModel;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;

import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.*;

public class SWTImageTools {

static BufferedImage convertToAWT(ImageData data) {
    ColorModel colorModel = null;
    PaletteData palette = data.palette;
    if (palette.isDirect) {
        colorModel = new DirectColorModel(data.depth, palette.redMask, palette.greenMask, palette.blueMask);
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(colorModel, colorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(data.width, data.height), false, null);
        for (int y = 0; y < data.height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < data.width; x++) {
                int pixel = data.getPixel(x, y);
                RGB rgb = palette.getRGB(pixel);
                bufferedImage.setRGB(x, y,  rgb.red << 16 | rgb.green << 8 | rgb.blue);
            }
        }
        return bufferedImage;
    } else {
        RGB[] rgbs = palette.getRGBs();
        byte[] red = new byte[rgbs.length];
        byte[] green = new byte[rgbs.length];
        byte[] blue = new byte[rgbs.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < rgbs.length; i++) {
            RGB rgb = rgbs[i];
            red[i] = (byte)rgb.red;
            green[i] = (byte)rgb.green;
            blue[i] = (byte)rgb.blue;
        }
        if (data.transparentPixel != -1) {
            colorModel = new IndexColorModel(data.depth, rgbs.length, red, green, blue, data.transparentPixel);
        } else {
            colorModel = new IndexColorModel(data.depth, rgbs.length, red, green, blue);
        }       
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(colorModel, colorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(data.width, data.height), false, null);
        WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
        int[] pixelArray = new int[1];
        for (int y = 0; y < data.height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < data.width; x++) {
                int pixel = data.getPixel(x, y);
                pixelArray[0] = pixel;
                raster.setPixel(x, y, pixelArray);
            }
        }
        return bufferedImage;
    }
}
```

this helped!